# Complete Classical Guitar Course-Guide?

Tags: guitar, learning, classical-guitar, self-learning

Here's my situation:

I have been playing guitar for 10 years, learning all the stuff on my own. I began with simple acoustic songs and after some time I started to play electric guitar, I studied and learned lot, and I was very disciplined about it (About that time, I learned very good and vast stuff from music theory and electric guitar techniques).

Now, I'm trying to learn classical guitar since 1 year ago, the problem is that I don't think my method is productive, what I'm actually doing is learning some thechniques of the classical guitar and improving my theory foundations, the problem is that I don't have a 'syllabus', so at the end I feel that what I'm doing is learning unordered stuff.

I don't know so much about the music pedagogy, I don't know if the best way of learning Classical Guitar is learning a bunch of pieces or learning techniques and theory first, or both.

What I'm asking for is an ordered course (e.g. pdf or online course) where I can study classical guitar in a progressive way, a course that gives me months of a good routine, of course, unfortunally I have not conditions for paying a course so I'm asking for free sources, I've searched the internet and I find a lot of good material but... SEPARATED MATERIAL, I need a study plan, and I really hope you can help me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you using any books?  If so, what are they?

Comment: Hi, I'm not using any specific material actually (except for the Carcassi's method that Kirk A. recommended me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I studied classical guitar, my teacher based his course on the [Carcassi Method](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Complete_Carcassi_Guitar_Method.html?id=tUMEwdfzHMwC). I would give it a thumbs up. Get a foot stool or use your guitar case as a prop in order to achieve the proper posture. Develop both the rest stroke and free stroke for your picking hand, and keep your fret hand thumb behind the neck rather than atop it. Best of luck! Enjoy yourself!

Answer (score 1):

I went to amazon.com and did a classical guitar book search, and evaluated based on the reviews.  It seemed to be somewhat of a draw between:

[The Christopher Parkening Guitar Method - Volume 1: Guitar Technique](http://amzn.com/B00FJ6E4K2)

[Solo Guitar Playing - Book 1](http://amzn.com/0825636795)

I settled on Parkening, but I haven't launched into it at all

Answer (score 1):

I started studying classical guitar 10 months ago. I am using the Carcassi method and have progressed through the keys of c,g,d,a,e, and am now beginning f. I find the method enjoyable and challenging. Be patient, strive for pure tones and "PRACTICE !". I had a thorough understanding of notage when I began(from piano) and I am sure it helped with my progress. I practice about 2 hours a day. By the way, I've never had a teacher.